# how to link a select field options with the database records

Tags: forms

i am doing some experiments within my custom form and that is to display a table record from database only corresponding to the product code (i.e sku) is selected from the select list. The database has following structure:

```
nid | sku | orderin | orderout | created
```

I want to link the sku in select list and the sku in database table so that when i select a sku then data corresponding to that sku should only display. Below is what I have done so far.

### Query for the select list

```
function formModule_display($form, &$form_state)
{

  // The form we are building
  $form = array();

 $result = db_query("SELECT o.nid, o.sku FROM {formmodule_order} o ");

    $options = array();
   foreach($result as $row) {
      $options[$row->nid] = $row->sku;

    }
```

### Query for record display

```
 $query = db_select('formmodule_order', 'h')
   ->fields('h',array('nid','sku','orderIn','orderOut','created'))
   ->orderBy('h.nid', 'ASC')
   ->condition('$options[$row->nid]', array('pen-11'));

    $result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: is there any method so that i can link the $options[$row->nid] = $row->sku; within the condition clause as this line of code - "->condition('$options[$row->nid]', array('pen-11'));" is giving error

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Form API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7), especially the [part about select lists](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#select):

```
<?php
   $form['selected'] = array(
       '#type' => 'select',
       '#title' => t('Selected'),
       '#options' => array(
          0 => t('No'),
         1 => t('Yes'),
       ),
       '#default_value' => $category['selected'],
       '#description' => t('Set this to <em>Yes</em> if you would like this category to be selected by default.'),
   );
?>
```

You can also consult the [examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples) for more information.